# Weird issue with jquery versions, ajax, and Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I'll save as much of the backstory as possible, but here's what I'm trying to figure out.

I have two dropdowns, the first is a list of states, the 2nd is the schools in that state. Changing the select triggers a listing of the schools with json and php.

Using jquery 1.3.2, everything works fine in Firefox and IE9. In IE8 I get a syntax error pointing to the 'for' loop and script does not work. If I can figure out what the issue is with the 'for' loop and can actually make the script work with 1.3.2, that's fine.

I tried upgrading to 1.4.4 or any newer version of jquery, and when I do that, the script doesn't work at all, in any browser and through research I haven't been able to figure out why.

For what it's worth I also used getJSON instead of ajax, if that makes a difference anywhere.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select#addr_state").change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'schools.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {id: $(this).val(), type: "list"},
        success: function(j){
            var options = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += "<option value='" + j[i].optionValue + "'>" + j[i].optionDisplay + "</option>";
            }
            $("select#school_id").html(options);
        }
    });     

  })
})
```

For those who wanted to see the error, it wouldn't let me post a screenshot as a new member. I am using browserstack to test and they are using CompanionJS. I get just "Syntax error" on line 41 (the for loop), then on line 42 "'OptionValue' is null or not an object", under that there are references to the jquery.min.js file, line 19.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Can you post your error, please?

Comment: What kind of error messages are you getting?  Use the developer tools in your browser to find out.

Comment: i would guess that if it's pointing to the for loop `j` is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Can you post your form and a sample json response you get that causes the issue in IE?

Comment: Yes, posting the JSON response sample would be really helpful. I would bet on malformed JSON in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you change:

```
options += "<option value=\"" + j[i].optionValue + "\">" + j[i].optionDisplay + "</option>";
```

to

```
options += "<option value='" + j[i].optionValue + "'>" + j[i].optionDisplay + "</option>";
```

does that help?

EDIT: another thing to try: us jQuery 1.7.1 and add/change to:

```
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
```

Help debug: change the for loop part to:(check if this start gets added and nothing else)

```
var options = "<option value='start'>start</option>";
if (j){
    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += "<option value='" + j[i].optionValue + "'>" + j[i].optionDisplay + "</option>";
    }
}
$(options).appendTo("select#school_id");
```

EDIT: Test page with the assumption of the properly formed results: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/m3A3w/

EDIT2: Anothere thing you MIGHT do is add json2.js (google it) and do:
alert(JSON.stringify(j)); RIGHT at the beginning of the success: function to verify your JSON structure.

Comment: The \ in the code is because my html is actually a variable in a php function. It doesn't actually render that way.

Comment: I would post EXACTLY what gets rendered in that case.

Comment: If I change to 1.7.1 and changed the datatype and add contenttype, it doesn't work at all. I added in the start option and it only adds it when it populates with the schools, I still get the same error messages as before.

Comment: @AllenHall - I added an example page that you might leverage.  See the ajaxError section as well to perhaps isolate errors.

Comment: So I added the json2 and the alert() line and it worked, meaning the output was displayed inside the alert window.